# Passing xml to stored procedure on linked server

Tags: sql-server, xml, linked-server

I've tried something like this:

```sql
declare @xml as xml
SET @xml =
             (
              SELECT DISTINCT 
                     123 AS IdUser
              FROM
                   (
                    SELECT 
                           1 AS a
                   ) AS ic FOR
              XML AUTO
    );
exec [linked_server_name].[mydb].[dbo].[stored_procedure] @xml=@xml
```

Got Msg 9514, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Tried converting input parameter to varchar(max) and converting it back inside linked server
Still got Msg 9514, Level 16, State 1, Line 5.
Tried executing via openquery - still got Msg 9514, Level 16, State 1, Line 5

Comment: Please edit your post and add the following: (1) entire error message, (2) source code of stored procedure, (3) what database and linked server driver behind the linked server.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, you were on the right path to a solution. If your database is SQL Server, passing XML via linked servers is not supported. Casting it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is a recommended workaround. Along the following:

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = 
CAST('' AS XML).query('
    element ic {
        attribute IdUser {"123"}
    }
    ');

DECLARE @par NVARCHAR(MAX) = CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

exec [linked_server_name].[mydb].[dbo].[stored_procedure] @xml=@par;
```